# Keyboard shortcut for folding code at current line in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

Is there a keyboard shortcut that is equivalent to clicking the collapse arrow that shows up next to the line numbers?

`CTRL-SHIFT-[` / `CTRL-SHIFT-]`  acts on the whole class, way outside my chosen line. If I do `CTRL-L` on a collapsed line then `CTRL-SHIFT-[` works for the uncollapsing a method. But I need to highlight the whole method to use `CTRL-SHIFT-]`.

Is there no other way to simulate "click the arrow next to the line number" using just the keyboard?